# Camera preview on multiple views - initialize/release handling

Tags: android, camera

I encapsulated the usage of the Android camera into one single class (CameraAccess) that uses an invisible SurfaceTexture as preview and which implements the Camera.PreviewCallback. Within this callback I get the byte array of the current frame which I then want to use on multiple views/fragments.

My problem is the life-cycle management. Usually the camera is used within a single View and initialized/release in onSurfaceCreated and onSurfaceDestroyed (see SurfaceHolder.Callback). But in my scenario I need to use the preview on more than one View. Each view adds itself as a callback to the CameraAccess class.

I thought to put the CameraAccess as a member into the Application class. But when you press the home button then the Application is still alive but all views are destroyed. How would you handle the init and release of the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved it.

There are some problems you need to solve. First, the matrix/color conversions of the OpenCV matrix, which is a very expensive operation in Android. Therefore, it is recommended to do that only once. This class makes also sure that the original matrix is only converted once and only if the UI is requesting the bitmap.

```
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public interface CameraFrame extends CvCameraViewFrame {
    Bitmap toBitmap();

    @Override
    Mat rgba();

    @Override
    Mat gray();
}
```

The implementation of this class looks like this:

```
    private class CameraAccessFrame implements CameraFrame {
        private Mat mYuvFrameData;
        private Mat mRgba;
        private int mWidth;
        private int mHeight;
        private Bitmap mCachedBitmap;
        private boolean mRgbaConverted;
        private boolean mBitmapConverted;

        @Override
        public Mat gray() {
            return mYuvFrameData.submat(0, mHeight, 0, mWidth);
        }

        @Override
        public Mat rgba() {
            if (!mRgbaConverted) {
                Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba,
                        Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12, 4);
                mRgbaConverted = true;
            }
            return mRgba;
        }

        @Override
        public Bitmap toBitmap() {
            if (mBitmapConverted)
                return mCachedBitmap;

            Mat rgba = this.rgba();
            Utils.matToBitmap(rgba, mCachedBitmap);
            mBitmapConverted = true;
            return mCachedBitmap;
        }

        public CameraAccessFrame(Mat Yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
            super();
            mWidth = width;
            mHeight = height;
            mYuvFrameData = Yuv420sp;
            mRgba = new Mat();

            this.mCachedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        public void release() {
            mRgba.release();
            mCachedBitmap.recycle();
        }

        public void invalidate() {
            mRgbaConverted = false;
            mBitmapConverted = false;
        }
    };
```

The Matrix conversion is done by the OpenCV Utils `org.opencv.android.Utils.matToBitmap(converted, bmp);`. Since we want to receive the camera image only once, but displaying it on multiple views, it is a 1:n relationship. The 1 is the component that receives the image (will be explained later), while the n is any UI view that wants to use the image. For those UI callbacks, I created this interface.

```
    public interface CameraFrameCallback {
        void onCameraInitialized(int frameWidth, int frameHeight);

        void onFrameReceived(CameraFrame frame);

        void onCameraReleased();
    }
```

It is implemented by the `CameraCanvasView`, which is an Android view. `SurfaceView` and `SurfaceHolder` can be found in `android.graphics`. The real UI of the view is the Surface. So, when the surface is created (show on the display), the view will register itself to the `CameraAccess` (the 1 from the 1:n relationship shown later). Whenever a new camera image is received by the `CameraAcess` it will invoke `onFrameReceived` on all registered callbacks. Since the view is such a callback, it will read the bitmap from the `CameraFrame` and display it.

```
public class CameraCanvasView extends SurfaceView implements CameraFrameCallback, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    Context context;
    CameraAccess mCamera;
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Rect mBackgroundSrc = new Rect();

    public CameraCanvasView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        this.context = context;

        SurfaceHolder sh = this.getHolder();
        sh.addCallback(this);

        setFocusable(true);

        this.mCamera = CameraAccess.getInstance(context,
                CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraInitialized(int frameWidth, int frameHeight) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFrameReceived(CameraFrame frame) {
        this.setBackgroundImage(frame.toBitmap());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraReleased() {

        setBackgroundImage(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        this.mCamera.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        this.mCamera.removeCallback(this);
    }

    public void setBackgroundImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.mBackground = image;

        if (image != null)
            this.mBackgroundSrc.set(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        else
            this.mBackgroundSrc.setEmpty();

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        if (mBackground != null && !mBackground.isRecycled())
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBackground, mBackgroundSrc, boundingBox, paint);
    }
}
```

Finally, you need the camera handler, the 1 in our 1:n relationship. This is the `CameraAccess`. It handles the camera initialization and registers itself as a callback that is notified by Android whenever a new frame is received. This is the `android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback`. The base class for this can be found in Android itself. The `CameraAccess` also holds one single `CameraAccessFrame` with one single OpenCV Matrix. Whenever a new image is received, that image is put to the existing OpenCV matrix thus overwriting the matrix values and invalidating the `CameraAcessFrame` to notify any UI element, that is bound to it. Overwriting an existing matrix is saving you memory operations for freeing and reserving memory. Therefore, do not destroy and recreate a matrix, but overwrite it. It is important to mention, that the `CameraAccess` is a logical invisible component and not a visual Android view. Usually camera images are directly shown on UI elements and Android needs a surface/view to render on. Since my component is invisible, I need to create a `SurfaceTexture` manually. The camera will automatically render into that texture.

```
public class CameraAccess implements Camera.PreviewCallback,
        LoaderCallbackInterface {

    // see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html for more
    // details

    final static String TAG = "CameraAccess";
    Context context;
    int cameraIndex; // example: CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT or
    // CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK
    Camera mCamera;
    int mFrameWidth;
    int mFrameHeight;
    Mat mFrame;
    CameraAccessFrame mCameraFrame;
    List<CameraFrameCallback> mCallbacks = new ArrayList<CameraFrameCallback>();
    boolean mOpenCVloaded;
    byte mBuffer[]; // needed to avoid OpenCV error:
                    // "queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned!"

    private static CameraAccess mInstance;

    public static CameraAccess getInstance(Context context, int cameraIndex) {
        if (mInstance != null)
            return mInstance;

        mInstance = new CameraAccess(context, cameraIndex);
        return mInstance;
    }

    private CameraAccess(Context context, int cameraIndex) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cameraIndex = cameraIndex;

        if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_7, context,
                this)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot connect to OpenCVManager");
        } else
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCVManager successfully connected");
    }

    private boolean checkCameraHardware() {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance(int cameraIndex) {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(cameraIndex); // attempt to get a
                                            // Camera
                                            // instance

            Log.d(TAG, "Camera opened. index: " + cameraIndex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    public void addCallback(CameraFrameCallback callback) {
        // we don't care if the callback is already in the list
        this.mCallbacks.add(callback);

        if (mCamera != null)
            callback.onCameraInitialized(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
        else if (mOpenCVloaded)
            connectCamera();
    }

    public void removeCallback(CameraFrameCallback callback) {
        boolean removed = false;
        do {
            // someone might have added the callback multiple times
            removed = this.mCallbacks.remove(callback);

            if (removed)
                callback.onCameraReleased();

        } while (removed == true);

        if (mCallbacks.size() == 0)
            releaseCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame, Camera arg1) {
        mFrame.put(0, 0, frame);
        mCameraFrame.invalidate();

        for (CameraFrameCallback callback : mCallbacks)
            callback.onFrameReceived(mCameraFrame);

        if (mCamera != null)
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
    }

    private void connectCamera() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (true) {// checkCameraHardware()) {
                mCamera = getCameraInstance(cameraIndex);

                Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

                // Camera.Size previewSize = sizes.get(0);
                Collections.sort(sizes, new PreviewSizeComparer());
                Camera.Size previewSize = null;
                for (Camera.Size s : sizes) {
                    if (s == null)
                        break;

                    previewSize = s;
                }

                // List<Integer> formats = params.getSupportedPictureFormats();
                // params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);

                params.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
                mCamera.setParameters(params);

                params = mCamera.getParameters();

                mFrameWidth = params.getPreviewSize().width;
                mFrameHeight = params.getPreviewSize().height;

                int size = mFrameWidth * mFrameHeight;
                size = size
                        * ImageFormat
                                .getBitsPerPixel(params.getPreviewFormat()) / 8;
                mBuffer = new byte[size];

                mFrame = new Mat(mFrameHeight + (mFrameHeight / 2),
                        mFrameWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                mCameraFrame = new CameraAccessFrame(mFrame, mFrameWidth,
                        mFrameHeight);

                SurfaceTexture texture = new SurfaceTexture(0);

                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(texture);
                    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
                    mCamera.startPreview();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Camera preview started");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                for (CameraFrameCallback callback : mCallbacks)
                    callback.onCameraInitialized(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

                mCamera.release();

                Log.d(TAG, "Preview stopped and camera released");
            }
            mCamera = null;

            if (mFrame != null) {
                mFrame.release();
            }

            if (mCameraFrame != null) {
                mCameraFrame.release();
            }

            for (CameraFrameCallback callback : mCallbacks)
                callback.onCameraReleased();
        }
    }

    public interface CameraFrameCallback {
        void onCameraInitialized(int frameWidth, int frameHeight);

        void onFrameReceived(CameraFrame frame);

        void onCameraReleased();
    }

    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        mOpenCVloaded = true;

        if (mCallbacks.size() > 0)
            connectCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPackageInstall(int operation,
            InstallCallbackInterface callback) {
    }

    private class PreviewSizeComparer implements Comparator<Camera.Size> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Size arg0, Size arg1) {
            if (arg0 != null && arg1 == null)
                return -1;
            if (arg0 == null && arg1 != null)
                return 1;

            if (arg0.width < arg1.width)
                return -1;
            else if (arg0.width > arg1.width)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Most of the code in `CameraAccess` is about the initialization and handling of the Android camera. I will not explain any further how a camera is being initialized. There is plenty of documentation out there.

**Update 12. May 2020:** On request, I added more details and explanation to the quite long code. In case of any further question about the other classes, let me know.

Comment: Hey @Matthias i am developing an CustomCaemra App. i had same Problem.i also want multiple camera Preview into single Activity[Like in GridView].Please help me How can i achive this..i already asked question but no one gave me answer....Here is my Question Link.......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392791/how-to-apply-custom-filters-in-a-camera-surfaceview-preview

Comment: i googled it and tried more tutorial's,libraries[grafica too].but i did not achive this type of Preview[Multiple Cmaera Preview]. i found more problem's same as my problem in Stackoverflow.but same as my Question no one gave answer's.Please see this Link i want this type of View....http://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHuj.jpg

Comment: You could use my code from above, but it is based on OpenCV. Within the class CameraAcessFrame I'm converting the OpenCV Matrix (the image data of the frame) into a Bitmap that can be used inside Android and in your application. So you could clone the Bitmap, apply your color filter and display it in a UI-view. See CameraCanvasView.onFrameReceived above.

Comment: ok Bro.thanks for your response.i will try as you say...once again thanks.

Comment: Hey @Matthias..i tried as you told..but i had some Problem's...Like i Used your code..but i can not found some of the class's & interface's that you defined in your above code.Then Please Help me out...and see i am not telling you to give me your whole project's...but i need only class's and interface's which you defined in your code.

Comment: if you don't mind then Please share your [Related class's and interface's] ..code with Stackoverflow. or send me on this Email--->sagaraghara7@gmail.com

Comment: i know your code will helpfull me or some other's User's on stackOverflow...Thanks

Comment: same problem with me, his code is incomplete and rather than sharing that whole class its better to highlight and explain the important methods at least.

Comment: @CosmicDev, I updated the post describing the different classes in detail. Also added the Android and OpenCV references.

Comment: @SagarAghara, I updated the post describing the different classes in detail. Also added the Android and OpenCV references.

Comment: @Matthias Can you please check my this post : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61746044/creating-canvas-on-top-of-surfaceview-android

Comment: @CosmicDev in your case you don't need my quite complex 1:n relationship which is also using OpenCV. You just need to follow the default Android instructions and then render the image into your surface. For the transparent SurfaceView you need to Google a bit. There are examples out there. [Start here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera)

Comment: @Matthias Check out this thread of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731115/cropping-a-full-screen-camera-image-bitmap-into-a-surface-view-height-and-width i got stuck at that point that's why i started looking for canvas, If you can help with this thread then it would be great.

Comment: and  a transparent surfaceview will not work as I have to show camera input too in both the surfaceviews

Comment: Sorry, but I haven’t done any Android development for years.

Comment: even the present guys are not able to help.